# How to Move Tooltip Away from Checkbox in Bootstrap Theme?

Tags: theming

I am using the Bootstrap theme as the administration theme. The tooltips get in the way of the checkboxes. How to move?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [Turn the Tooltip Bootstrap functionality off][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414244/turn-the-tooltip-bootstrap-functionality-off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the settings for your theme under the appearance tab there should be a javascript tab. If you click that the tooltips and popover settings are displayed. You can either turn them off or make them appear below the field.

Comment: This is useful. Means the loss of the tooltips of course.

Comment: Not if you just choose to change the location of the tooltip instead turning them off completely.

Comment: Yes there are a lot of options under 'options'.